# Difference between cucumber run and calabash-android run command?

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-android, calabash-ios

Please clarify when do we use $cucumber run and when do we use $calabash-android run test.apk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either honestly, it's mostly semantics. `calabash-android run` invokes cucumber.